# Html5 validation error with title tag

Tags: validation, html

Hello I am validating my source against html 5.

But I am getting this error and have now idea how to solve it:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Rode kruis Vrijwilligers applicatie</title><link href="/css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

This is the error:

XHTML element title not allowed as child of XHTML element meta in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Any idea's?

Comment: There's an open bug for the validator for this issue: http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=9967 . There is no justification for switching to XHTML validating mode just because of the presence of the xmlns attribute on the html element, but it seems that's what the validator does.

Comment: title tag does not belong in meta tag...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XHTML which is strict about XML rules, every tag that is opened should be nested and closed properly, tags such as `<area />,<base />,<basefont />,<br />,<hr />,<input />,<img />,<link />,<meta />` are only usefull with attributes so you have to close them by "/>" instead of ">"
In XML thats how you open and close a tag in the same tag, this is what your html should look like:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Rode kruis Vrijwilligers applicatie</title>
    <link href="/css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
   </head>
   <body>
    Test.
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your `meta` tag - it is an empty tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

XHTML is an XML dialect, so empty elements should be closed (so `<br>` is not valid XHTML, but `<br />` is).

Comment: Which (if I'm not mistaken) is a requirement only if you declare your HTML5 document to be xhtml compliant. HTML5 itself doesn't require you to close tags like that, though it may still be good practice. Also, in the code sample from the question the 'link' tag needs to be closed similarly.

Comment: This is my doctype declaration: <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="nl" xml:lang="nl">

Comment: @sanders - looks like you _are_ declaring your HTML as XML, XHTML specifically (see the xmlns attribute).

Comment: hmm i just want html and not xhtml

Comment: @sanders - drop the `xmlns` attribute and any other `xml:` attributes and re-validate.

Comment: Aye then it's the xmlns....nl" bit that's requiring (amongst other things) you to close elements. If you'd leave that out good chance the HTML5 validation will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments to the first answer (which should also solve the problem) another approach is to use plain HTML5 without the XML requirement. For example the following code would get validated:

```
<!doctype html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Rode kruis Vrijwilligers applicatie</title><link href="/css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
</head><body>Test.</body></html>
```

With the middle line being the original code.

Validated with direct input here:
http://validator.w3.org/