# Element title not allowed as child of element head in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html

I'm getting the error in W3C Validator. I have closed all the  so that isn't the issue. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<!-- Site Title -->
<title><?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> | <?php echo the_title(); ?></title>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html5 validation error with title tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850683/html5-validation-error-with-title-tag)

Comment: The relevant code here would be the generated HTML, and not PHP. So show us that, if you still need our help after checking the duplicate. And also show us the full document from the beginning.

Comment: Read through this one has not got the same issue with the one I'm having

Comment: Well then edit your question please, and add actual _relevant_ code/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a search engine typing: "wordpress the_title()" I get the first result with a link going to this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Now that page says:

> Displays or returns the unescaped title of the current post. This tag
>   may only be used within The Loop, **to [get the title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) of a post outside
>   of the loop use get_the_title**. If the post is protected or private,
>   this will be noted by the words "Protected: " or "Private: " prepended
>   to the title.

So the problem you see / have is that `the_title()` also renders `<h1>` or similar tags which are not allowed inside the `<title>` tag from the `<header>`

This is what you need to know about the `<title>` element

> The HTML  element defines the title of the document, shown in a
>   browser's title bar or on the page's tab. **It can only contain text**,
>   and any contained tags are ignored.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title